# Part of description on "Tags" page is invisible

Tags: support, design

On ["Tags" page](https://askubuntu.com/tags), longer descriptions are clipped and the text that exceeds is invisible, so it can't be accessed.

It often occurs with my Firefox minimum font size to 16 (Options > Content > Fonts & Colors > Advanced > Minimum font size).

Here's a screen-shot of the bug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We don't support arbitrary font size adjustment in this manner.

We support +1 and -1 font size only, and of course infinite browser zoom.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html